# Regex String confusion and string parse

Tags: regex, powershell

Previously I was show on stack a good way to parse a string by using Regex.
https://regex101.com/r/BHamf0/1 was the result.

Today I need to parse the following string and find if `enableCollaborativeInbox:` is `true` or `false`

```
Group: dir@domain.com
  Group Settings:        
    id: <ID Num> 
    name: Dir
    description:
    directMembersCount: 0
    adminCreated: True
    allowExternalMembers: false
    allowWebPosting: true
    archiveOnly: false
    customFooterText:
    customReplyTo:
    customRolesEnabledForSettingsToBeMerged: false
    defaultMessageDenyNotificationText:
    defaultSender: DEFAULT_SELF
    enableCollaborativeInbox: false
    includeCustomFooter: false
    includeInGlobalAddressList: true
    isArchived: true
    membersCanPostAsTheGroup: true
    messageModerationLevel: MODERATE_NONE
    replyTo: REPLY_TO_IGNORE
    sendMessageDenyNotification: false
    spamModerationLevel: ALLOW
    whoCanContactOwner: ALL_MANAGERS_CAN_CONTACT
    whoCanJoin: INVITED_CAN_JOIN
    whoCanLeaveGroup: NONE_CAN_LEAVE
    whoCanPostMessage: ANYONE_CAN_POST
    whoCanViewGroup: ALL_MEMBERS_CAN_VIEW
    whoCanViewMembership: ALL_MEMBERS_CAN_VIEW
    whoCanDiscoverGroup: ALL_MEMBERS_CAN_DISCOVER
      showInGroupDirectory: false
    whoCanAssistContent: NONE
      whoCanAssignTopics: NONE
      whoCanEnterFreeFormTags: NONE
      whoCanHideAbuse: NONE
      whoCanMakeTopicsSticky: NONE
      whoCanMarkDuplicate: NONE
      whoCanMarkFavoriteReplyOnAnyTopic: NONE
      whoCanMarkNoResponseNeeded: NONE
      whoCanModifyTagsAndCategories: NONE
      whoCanTakeTopics: NONE
      whoCanUnassignTopic: NONE
      whoCanUnmarkFavoriteReplyOnAnyTopic: NONE
    whoCanModerateContent: OWNERS_AND_MANAGERS
      whoCanApproveMessages: OWNERS_AND_MANAGERS
      whoCanDeleteAnyPost: OWNERS_AND_MANAGERS
      whoCanDeleteTopics: OWNERS_AND_MANAGERS
      whoCanLockTopics: OWNERS_AND_MANAGERS
      whoCanMoveTopicsIn: OWNERS_AND_MANAGERS
      whoCanMoveTopicsOut: OWNERS_AND_MANAGERS
      whoCanPostAnnouncements: OWNERS_AND_MANAGERS
    whoCanModerateMembers: OWNERS_AND_MANAGERS
      whoCanAdd: ALL_MANAGERS_CAN_ADD
      whoCanApproveMembers: ALL_MANAGERS_CAN_APPROVE
      whoCanBanUsers: OWNERS_AND_MANAGERS
      whoCanInvite: ALL_MANAGERS_CAN_INVITE
      whoCanModifyMembers: OWNERS_AND_MANAGERS
    Deprecated:
      allowGoogleCommunication: false
      favoriteRepliesOnTop: true
      maxMessageBytes: 25M
      messageDisplayFont: DEFAULT_FONT
      whoCanAddReferences: NONE
      whoCanMarkFavoriteReplyOnOwnTopic: NONE
  Non-Editable Aliases: (1)
    alias: dir@domain.com.test-google-a.com
  Members: (0)
  Total Members in Group: 0
```

I tried to use the previous examples with https://regex101.com/r/BHamf0/1 and had no success. I am not sure why.
The goal is to learn if `enableCollaborativeInbox:` is `true` or `false`

Pervious PS code that worked

```
    $regex = '(?s)^.+\bCurrent: ([\d.]+).+\bLatest: ([\d.]+).*$'
    $CurrentVersion, $LatestVersion = -split (($GAMCheck -join "`n") -replace $regex, '$1 $2')
```

And the pervious string

```
GAMADV-XTD3 6.07.31 - https://github.com/taers232c/GAMADV-XTD3 - pyinstaller
Ross Scroggs <ross.scroggs@gmail.com>
Python 3.9.7 64-bit final
Windows 10 10.0.18363 SP0 Multiprocessor Free AMD64
Path: C:\GAMADV-XTD3
Config File: C:\GAMConfig\gam.cfg, Section: DEFAULT, customer_id: C047encoi, domain: sonos.com        
Version Check:
  Current: 6.07.31
   Latest: 6.07.31
```

Comment: This is tagged [tag:powershell] - what PowerShell commands or code did you use?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen good point. I added the pervious PS code and added a tag.

Comment: Is that a known file format? It looks like UAML (but isn't)... Maybe there is a parser library available for it like `powershell-yaml` so you can simply call `ConvertFrom-XXXX`...

Comment: @jessehouwing I doubt it but I will look. The string gets produced from a GAM command. <https://github.com/taers232c/GAMADV-XTD3>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Match operator and a look-behind-assertion to find the label, then capture the value:

```
  $raw -match "(?<=enableCollaborativeInbox:\s+).*"
  $Matches[0] -eq "true"
```

Comment: This will return `$true` if the value in the file is `false`

Comment: This worked like ```$i = gam info group 'dir@domain.com'

$enableCollaborativeInbox = $i -match "(?<=enableCollaborativeInbox:).*"

If ($enableCollaborativeInbox -like "*False*") {
    Write-Warning 'Hi'
}```

Comment: @dcaz updated the example. Thanks for spot checking. PowerShell is weird as usual...

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-match` operator to test for the presence of `enableCollaborativeInbox:`  and capture the value following it:

```
$s = @'
Group: dir@domain.com
  Group Settings:        
    id: <ID Num> 
    name: Dir
    description:
    directMembersCount: 0
    adminCreated: True
    allowExternalMembers: false
    allowWebPosting: true
    archiveOnly: false
    customFooterText:
    customReplyTo:
    customRolesEnabledForSettingsToBeMerged: false
    defaultMessageDenyNotificationText:
    defaultSender: DEFAULT_SELF
    enableCollaborativeInbox: false
    includeCustomFooter: false
    includeInGlobalAddressList: true
    isArchived: true
    membersCanPostAsTheGroup: true
    messageModerationLevel: MODERATE_NONE
    replyTo: REPLY_TO_IGNORE
    sendMessageDenyNotification: false
    spamModerationLevel: ALLOW
    whoCanContactOwner: ALL_MANAGERS_CAN_CONTACT
    whoCanJoin: INVITED_CAN_JOIN
    whoCanLeaveGroup: NONE_CAN_LEAVE
    whoCanPostMessage: ANYONE_CAN_POST
    whoCanViewGroup: ALL_MEMBERS_CAN_VIEW
    whoCanViewMembership: ALL_MEMBERS_CAN_VIEW
    whoCanDiscoverGroup: ALL_MEMBERS_CAN_DISCOVER
      showInGroupDirectory: false
    whoCanAssistContent: NONE
      whoCanAssignTopics: NONE
      whoCanEnterFreeFormTags: NONE
      whoCanHideAbuse: NONE
      whoCanMakeTopicsSticky: NONE
      whoCanMarkDuplicate: NONE
      whoCanMarkFavoriteReplyOnAnyTopic: NONE
      whoCanMarkNoResponseNeeded: NONE
      whoCanModifyTagsAndCategories: NONE
      whoCanTakeTopics: NONE
      whoCanUnassignTopic: NONE
      whoCanUnmarkFavoriteReplyOnAnyTopic: NONE
    whoCanModerateContent: OWNERS_AND_MANAGERS
      whoCanApproveMessages: OWNERS_AND_MANAGERS
      whoCanDeleteAnyPost: OWNERS_AND_MANAGERS
      whoCanDeleteTopics: OWNERS_AND_MANAGERS
      whoCanLockTopics: OWNERS_AND_MANAGERS
      whoCanMoveTopicsIn: OWNERS_AND_MANAGERS
      whoCanMoveTopicsOut: OWNERS_AND_MANAGERS
      whoCanPostAnnouncements: OWNERS_AND_MANAGERS
    whoCanModerateMembers: OWNERS_AND_MANAGERS
      whoCanAdd: ALL_MANAGERS_CAN_ADD
      whoCanApproveMembers: ALL_MANAGERS_CAN_APPROVE
      whoCanBanUsers: OWNERS_AND_MANAGERS
      whoCanInvite: ALL_MANAGERS_CAN_INVITE
      whoCanModifyMembers: OWNERS_AND_MANAGERS
    Deprecated:
      allowGoogleCommunication: false
      favoriteRepliesOnTop: true
      maxMessageBytes: 25M
      messageDisplayFont: DEFAULT_FONT
      whoCanAddReferences: NONE
      whoCanMarkFavoriteReplyOnOwnTopic: NONE
  Non-Editable Aliases: (1)
    alias: dir@domain.com.test-google-a.com
  Members: (0)
  Total Members in Group: 0
'@

if($s -match 'enableCollaborativeInbox:\s*(\S+)'){
  [bool]::Parse($Matches[1])
}
```

Comment: Thanks as always!